# A word to describe the expected amount of information gained from learning the answer to a given question

Tags: single-word-requests

In relation to my [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3150345) on Mathematics.SE, I would like to know what English words would fit the best to describe the expected amount of information that will be gained by learning the answer to a given question or by learning the responses to a given questionnaire.

The word should describe the question or the questionnaire, not the answers.  Thus, words like "informativeness" or "information value" would fit poorly, because the common view is that the information is contained in answers, not in questions (though in fact both are important).

For example, the value that is to be described is *a priori* higher for the question "What is your favourite dish?" than for the question "Do you like French fries?"  It is also *a priori* higher for the question "Are you married?" than for the questions "Do you pay taxes?" and "Are you a lawyer?" (assuming nothing is known about the person being asked, the answers to the last two questions are easier to guess in advance -- "yes" and "no" respectively).

Usage examples:

> The question "What is your favourite dish?" has higher *foo* (or more *foo*) than the question "Do you like French fries?"
>
> The total *foo* of a questionnaire composed of completely independent questions is the sum of the *foo*s of its questions.

I know that this is an instance of [*entropy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) value, but I am looking for a more common and intuitive term, if such exists.

Comment: Please provide an example sentence.

Comment: I don't see a problem with saying that one question has more *information value* than another question. After all, answering it *will* provide more information. If you already *knew* the answer, you wouldn't normally ask the question in the first place. (And the same is true of Socratic questioning where you are trying to get the person answering to provide more information for themselves.)

Comment: @JasonBassford, it feels to me that it is rather "one question has more value than another for getting information."

Comment: @Alexey But how is *more value* any different than *information value*? Surely, the value of the question *lies* in the amount of information it will return when answered. Or, if not, how is the value being measured? (Like in physics and descriptions of energy, I suppose you could say that a question has *potential information value*, while an answer has *kinetic information value*.)

Comment: @JasonBassford, *potential information value* seems closer. I do not think a question *contains* information. It is about measuring how *efficient* the question is for extracting information (if it is answered).

Comment: It is odd that information theory does not have a term of art for this concept, which I assume is the case because your linked question evinces a grasp of that discipline.  Consequently, you'll probably need a metaphor, and I would nominate "efficiency" unless the word is otherwise occupied in the relevant domain. Wouldn't the question that produces the answer that most reduces the entropy of the system be the most efficient question?

Comment: @remarkl, in information theory this is called just *entropy*. I was looking for a more common and intuitive term.  *Efficiency* seems to be in the right direction, but not very descriptive.

Comment: @Alexy why didn't you just say that to begin with? The answer is 'entropy'. Is there a single word for that that is more informal? No.

Comment: @Mitch, how does knowing that the "entropy" term is applicable in information theory can help to conclude that there is no common word for this kind of a concept?

Comment: @Alexy knowing the concept tells you nothing about  what the labels are. I am just telling you outright. Aside from that, you asked for a word that you already knew.

Comment: @Alexey  I guess it's a question of how far from math you want to go.  "Pertinence" would capture the idea in a legal setting.

Comment: A word commonly used to describe the (relative) quantitative  value of a question is **weight**.  Compare: https://books.google.com/books?id=VlLICgAAQBAJ&pg=PA147&dq=%22weight+of+the+question%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj015KWx4fhAhXEmOAKHUyyDxUQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=%22weight%20of%20the%20question%22&f=false

Comment: @Mitch, there is a difference between "What is the name of the common food aditive that can be made from seawater by evaporation?" (salt) and "What is the name of the ionic compound with the chemical formula NaCl?" (sodium chloride).  Should i retag my question or add something to it to clarify that i was looking for a commonly understood word?

Comment: @TRomano, it seems to me that (relative) "weights" are about comparing several questions in a certain context. I am interested in some kind of an intrinsic value of a single question (though different questions can be compared by this value).

Comment: In simple terms, questions are *broad* or *open-ended* as opposed to *narrow* or *restrictive*.

Comment: I would use "value" but explain what it is standing in for, as in: "The total value (technically, the 'entropy') of a questionnaire composed of completely independent questions is the sum of the values of its questions."

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned the technical term

> [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory))

which means, in the information theory sense, the number of bits of information in a message, or likewise the thing you are asking for. It is however pretty technical, and also has its provably equivalent but equally obscure interpretation in thermodynamics. As such, replacing the informal phrase 'amount of information' with entropy will be only understood under very technical contexts.

You may be looking for an informal synonym, one that can replace 'entropy' to get the same idea, analogous to your example of 'salt' for 'sodium chloride'. As 'entropy' is [a latter day technical invention for a new concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_entropy) (by Rudolf Clausius in 1854), there is no existing informal older term.

So, **there is no single informal word for entropy**.

That's a hard thing to prove definitively (as opposed to suggesting a term that every one can see and judge yes or no). But the timing of the term is some justification that it is unlikely.

Asking for a single word for a complex concept is expecting a lot of any language. English and more likely its fans may have spoiled you by popularizing all the ineffable situations that turn out to have single words for them (eg 'justice', 'game', 'ineffable')

However, there may well be near enough synonyms or synonymous phrases for the concept. The title **'amount of information'** is sufficient or even simply

> **'information'**.

Answer (score 1):

One question can be a better **[discriminator](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/discriminator)** than another.

> A characteristic which enables people or things to be distinguished from one another.

[Oxford]

Although the question does not contain the sought-after information, one question has the ability to elicit more information than another. You will find references in the psychological testing domain to high-information yielding questions as *good discriminators*.  For instance, if a particular math problem covaries meaningfully with IQ, that problem is said to be a good discriminator for IQ.

If I'm trying to find a criminal suspect who is an American male, the question "Is he over 7 feet" is a poor discriminator, because it provides very little information for the answer "no". An If I use the median of the population of 5 feet, 9.5 inches, the question is guaranteed to eliminate half the population, which is the maximum one can guarantee, regardless of the answer.

Comment: Thanks, i'll think about it.  I was also thinking about "inquiring power", "examination value"...

Comment: *Discriminatory value* would fit then.